# Using Bootstrap 3, is there a way to reuse the same HTML for different media queries to practice DRY?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been reading Bootstrap 3's documents about modals, and it makes sense to use this HTML for the modal content. I'd be creating this modal on mobile:

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is, I'd want to reuse the HTML inside the body of the modal for a sidebar on the desktop media query. How would I do so without repeating the HTML for a second time as a completely different div that simply contains the exact same content?

Comment: if you have something like angularjs, you could use a template. If you have nothing, you could store the html in a JS variable (but this would be difficult to work with). What tech are you working with?

Comment: @Vinny Hi Vinny, I'm just using customizing bootstrap 3, not really using any additional tech. I thought a JS variable may be the way to go, was wondering if there was any better way to do it. Maybe not!

Comment: Yeah, if all you have is bootstrap this will be a bit difficult. the JS var will be very hard to read, and not readily apparent what's happening in your HTML code, which is why I am hesitant to recommend it.

Comment: As @Vinny mentioned, if you have AngularJS, you can create a directive with the transclude option enabled. It is explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)